# How do I access .env variables and use it inside the cypress.json file?

Tags: cypress

I have five different cypress projects in the same repo.

The Cypress.json file of each project has reporterOptions :

```
{
  "fixturesFolder": "./src/fixtures",
  "integrationFolder": "./src/integration",
   ……..
  "reporter": "../../node_modules/mocha-testrail-reporter",
  "reporterOptions": {
    "username": "my-user-name”,
    "password": "my-password",
    "host": "https://abc.testrail.io",
    "domain": "abc.testrail.io",
    "projectId": 1,
    "suiteId": 3,
    "includeAllInTestRun": true,
    "runName": "test"
  }
}
```

The Username, host, password and domain value are same for all five cypress projects. Thus, I want to put them in the .env file like this, and access these variables and use them in the Cypress.json files

```
USERNAME= my-user-name
PASSWORD= my-password
HOST= https://abc.testrail.io
DOMAIN= abc.testrail.io
```

How do I access these variables? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use .env variables inside cypress.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70333682/how-to-use-env-variables-inside-cypress-json-file)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Extending the Cypress Config File](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/18/extending-the-cypress-config-file/)

> Cypress does not support extends syntax in its configuration file

But in plugins it can be done

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {

  const reporterParams = require('.env')  // not quite sure of the format
                                          // may need to fiddle it

  const reportOptions = {
    ...config.reporterOptions,  // spread existing options
    "username": reporterParams.username,
    "password": reporterParams.password,
    "host": reporterParams.host,
    "domain": reporterParams.domain,
  }

  const merged = {
    ...config,
    reportOptions 
  }

  return merged
}
```