# Load environment variables from .env in Cypress (vite build)

Tags: testing, environment-variables, cypress, environment

### Cypress test

I am writing a cypress test for my Ionic React app, compiled using vite. Specifically, I want to intercept a request to my endpoint:

```js
const baseUrl = someBaseUrl;
cy.intercept(`${baseUrl}/home`);
```

Now, because the baseUrl is specific to my environment, I declare it in my `.env` file and specify it in `.env.local` in root:

```
VITE_BASE_URL = https://example.com
```

Now the problem is, that it is not that trivial to load variables form `.env`.

### What I tried

1. The naive approach is to just loaf id the same way I would load it elsewhere in the app:

   ```js
   const baseUrl = import.meta.env. VITE_BASE_URL // undefined
   ```
2. Then next I turned to the [Cypredd docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env). Cypress offers `Cypress.env()` but this does not load the variables from `.env` but from `cypress.config.ts`. This means I would have to duplicate all variables in `.env` to the `cypress.config.ts` to have them available in my tests. This solution is presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70333682/how-to-use-env-variables-inside-cypress-json-file) for example.
3. I also tried using [cypress-dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-dotenv) with this configuration:

   ```js
   // cypress/plugins/index.js
   const dotenvPlugin = require('cypress-dotenv');
   module.exports = (on, config) => {
     config = dotenvPlugin(config)
   return config
   }
   ```

   Sadly, this configuration does not work because the module cannot be found. This might be because `cypress-dotenv`has never been updated in two years while cypress received five major updates.
4. And I tried to this code snipped which I got from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75903967/how-can-i-specify-env-file-to-use-for-my-dev-server-when-running-cypress-tests):

   ```js
   const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

   module.exports = defineConfig({
     e2e: {
       setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
         config.env = {
           ...process.env,                 // add all process env var here
           ...config.env                   // plus any command line overrides
         }
         return config     
       },
     },
   })
   ```

While this solution will work for many, it does not in my specific case. This is because I use Vita to compile and also because my config is written in typescript so the syntax is a bit different too.

### Question

**Is there any easy way, to directly use variables from .env in Cypress?**

And how can this not be a very standard problem with a very standard solution?

### Solution

Eventually, I found that I don't even have to go the detour via the `setupNodeEvents()` function. Vite has its own `loadEnv` function, wich makes it very easy to set up the variables in the cypress config:

```js
// cypress.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';
import { loadEnv } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  // ... other configs
  env: {a
    ...loadEnv("development", process.cwd()) // inserts all environment variables
  }
});
```

And then in my cypress code, they are available like this:

```js
const baseUrl = Cypress.env('MY_BYSE_URL');
```

Comment: I was going to suggest `dotenv` but you posted your example - it looks out of date (the package docs have not been updated since Cypress v9). Can you confirm you are using a recent version of Cypress?

Comment: BTW the link for my suggestion is [How can I specify .env file...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75903967/how-can-i-specify-env-file-to-use-for-my-dev-server-when-running-cypress-tests)

Comment: Or this one [How can I get Vite env variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75310937/how-can-i-get-vite-env-variables) - but I don't think vite has much bearing on the problem.